# Need to set up alert if messages not consumed in service bus queue?

Tags: azure, alert, message, kql, servicebus

1. i selected service bus-> alert-> create Alertrule-> signal-> custom log search
   creating query for message not consumed for more than 2 hour in service bus queue but unable to find message detail data in Azure diagnostics table.
   Can nayone help me how to achive this alert rule

i tried by enabling Diagnostic setting in service bus namespace to collect the diagnostic log. but not able to find the messages detail

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far? @laxmi

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, enable `diagnostic settings` in the service bus namespace as you already did. Once it is done, use below log query to retrieve consumed messages more than 2 hours in service bus queue once you selected `custom log search signal` when creating an alert rule.

```bash
AzureDiagnostics
| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.SERVICEBUS" and Resource contains "newq" 
| where Category == "Messages"
| where ActivityName_s == "Completed"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(2h)
| project Message, Resource
```

*Alert rule created successfully:*

[image]

Refer [categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/monitor-service-bus-reference#azure-monitor-logs-tables) of Azure service bus detailed in MS Doc.